# .htaccess block bots starting with the string "bot"

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I currently have the following rules in my `.htaccess` file, I am using WordPress and this is the code that I came up with by searching the web,

```
# BLOCK BAD BOTS
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /  

 SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^$" keep_out
 SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent ^$ keep_out
 SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent (casper|cmsworldmap|diavol|dotbot)   keep_out
 SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent (flicky|ia_archiver|jakarta|kmccrew) keep_out
 SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent (libwww|planetwork|pycurl|skygrid)   keep_out
 SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent (purebot|comodo|feedfinder) keep_out
 SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent (scanner|crawl|robot|spider) keep_out
 <Limit GET POST PUT>
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from all
  Deny from env=keep_out
 </Limit>
</IfModule>


RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^-?$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^-?$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^bot\*$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^HEAD$ [OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/robots\.txt
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

But I see my server logs and I find one bot was able to get access, it is described as follows,

**bot with string "bot" followed by one of the following symbols -()&?**

So my question

1) How do I remove bots that start with the characters "bot"

2) Also do check and tell me if you see any issues with the current rules.

3) I am using both **SetEnvIfNoCase**  and **RewriteCond** is this valid?

Answer (score 0):

Change your blocking rule to this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^-?$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^-?$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^bot [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^HEAD$ [OR,NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/robots\.txt [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

Comment: Make sure this is **very first rule** in your .htaccess and then check from Apache logs what USER_AGENT value you see in access logs

Comment: i see this 140.174.72.247 - - [17/Dec/2015:09:18:53 -0700] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "-"  ..i am having a caching plugins and backup plugins on my site do they show up as "user agent with empty string"?

Comment: i made that the very first rule still i get 200 ok by using botsimulator.com

Comment: If Apache access log is showing empty user agent then this rule will not work because Apache is not getting original user_agent in request

Comment: i am getting this and the above rule like you suggested stil does not work for Unknown robot (identified by 'bot' followed by a space or one of the following characters _+:,.;/\-)

Comment: You wrote **they show up as "user agent with empty string"** so obviously it won't work with empty string